# How to remove special character from c9.io editor

Tags: editor, c9.io

I'm using the c9.io default editor and am getting an orange T in one of my files.  Does anyone know how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orange "T" is displaying where someone else's cursor is on a different window. It could also be yours.

## Fix It

Close any other windows you have open that have this workspace on it. If you've shared the workspace with someone, simply tell them to get off the workspace, you can do this by going to **Collaborate** > **Chat** and telling them to.
If all else fails, you may have the tab open on another computer and may just need to close that. Happy Coding!